# Splitting a USB-C for aux power

Tags: power, usb, usb-c, usb-hub, usb-pd

I'm building a mechanical keyboard and I need more current from my PC than I can get from one usb port. Can buy/make a usb splitter that I can plug into two A ports on my PC and plug into my USB-C MCU? The MCU in question can handle up to 2A and I don't need that much...but I do need more than 900mA.

Am I better off designing my keyboard with a second usb port for additional power? (In which case I'll need to ask another question to understand how!)

Comment: why does your keyboard need 2 amps?

Comment: Led strip. Even at half brightness, all the LEDs together will exceed 900mA, let alone the current the MCU itself needs. I probably won't need 2A...but definitely more than .9A

Comment: did you test the brightness? 10W of LED light is quite a lot

Comment: Sounds like your LED strip choice is not quite appropriate for the application, unless you want to fully illuminate the whole room.

Comment: Honestly, I have not! They've only arrived today and I haven't gotten home from work yet. But I can't wait until after I've put everything together before finding out that I have to turn the brightness down lower than I'd like in order to not trip a fuse. So I want to make atleast another 500mA available now so I have some wiggle room.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well most use them for underglow, not per-key lighting like I want to. So yes, just a little inappropriate ;)

Comment: Anyway, if you want to go with this concept anyway, you can look around for "USB Y-cable".

Comment: I did look into these but I couldn't find one that was usb A on the split end, and usb C on the other. I also wanted to get some info on how to wire one myself so I can braid and coil it. I need the split end quite short and the other quite long!

Comment: You could also get a powered USB hub, if you don't mind plugging another power supply into the wall.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I wanted to avoid it if at all possible, otherwise I'll have to buy another powerstrip. Plus I'd like to use the keyboard at work, where I won't have another outlet.

Comment: On a recent design I decided to use some tiny addressable LEDs as status indicators (SK6805-2427, smaller than the standard 5050 size). When I powered it up I realised they were way too bright... had to scale the max brightness from 255 all the way down to 32!

Comment: You can't just connect two USB-A host ports together and hope that it'll work with a USB-C port. Partly because you're connecting two different power supplies together, which is never good (though might not cause a problem if they're on the same PC) but mainly because the power signalling used by USB-C ports won't be implemented to let the device know how much power is available.

Comment: @Finbarr yea, it's looking more and more like I'll have to bite the bullet and use a powered hub. If my MCU didn't use usb C, then, I might've been able to get away with this?

Comment: Maybe, possibly, perhaps, but only really because a lot of USB host ports don't implement or enforce the proper power management specifications or processes.

Comment: 3V per LED x 1A = 3W. Modern LEDS are capable of 150+ l/W so 450l available. You can light 1.5 square meters (about 15 square feet) of area ton the brightness of a good bright monitor screen at full brightness with that much light. Less will be adequate.  Even at much lower efficiency 'less will be adequate'.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon more like 5V x .08A = .4W per one of my led packages. Works out to 375l....do I have that right? Still very bright!

Comment: @AerosolSP  I was reckoning what the actual LEDs will give at a given current. Typical white or blue EDs are about 3V. 5V will be dropped in some manner - or they may be in series wit an inverter. I'd need to know how many LEDs at 80 mA each. My original calculation probably applies. || How many LEDs? What colour? How are they driven?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's an RGBW led strip, SK2812. I'm using 63 of them, and each package has 4 leds (rgb and white) that according to the datasheet, each draw 20 mA at full brightness. It runs off of 5 or 12V, but will be 5V for my application.

Comment: @AerosolSP That's still somewhat confusing. 4 per pkg at 20 mA per LED x 63 pkgs = 4 x 20 x 63 = 5040 mA. If they are RGBW and only run at the equivalent of one full drive LED at one time that's 1260 mA. One LED at 3V (balance in controller) x 20 mA = 60 mW = about 6 lumen at 100 l/W and 9 l at 150 l/w. At 6 l that's 63 x 6 ~= 380 l = about good for a square metre at 'bright'.  Even allowing for varying l/W with colour it's still likely that you don't need 20 mA average per pkg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design your project with USB C and a C to C cable in mind.

Eve though USB A ports on a desktop only provide about 900ma, the USB C ports on a desktop machine typically provide higher currents, up to 3A.

On your board, measure the voltage on both CC pins using a 10K resistor and then to your microcontrollers ADC, and take the highest voltage of the 2 measurements.

- If you measure above 1.31V, the downstream facing device advertises
  maximum 3A, meaning it is good enough for all your device features
- If you measure above 0.70V, the downstream facing device advertises
  maximum 1.5A, so you limit the brightness/max PWM in software to stay
  under the limit
- If you are communicating USB 3.2 dual lane to the other device, your
  limit is 1.5A
- If you are communicating USB 3.2 single lane to the other device,
  your limit is 0.9A
- If you are communicating USB 2.0 to the other device, your limit is
  0.5A
- Otherwise, the host must be in suspend, so the limit is 0.1A

By gracefully reducing the maximum consumption based on the advertised values, you increase compatibility with other devices

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing: my desktop machine has no USB C ports, so I'm ultimately limited anyway!